# Is using netcat illegal?

Tags: legal, tools

Is using netcat to connect with a server that one does not own, illegal? For example, using netcat to connect with a web server and querying `GET / HTTP/1.1` etc.

I am asking this question because netcat is on bit on offensive side too, so maybe any use on a server would be illegal.

The very reason for my question is that because now a days several IT firms like those making anti-malwares take netcat as a malicious software, and also it can be used like nmap for scanning, so(just a guess) may be the tool can be got detected(as a scanner) while even creating a legal connection.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is requesting legal advice, which not only may vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction but also from case to case, and so should be obtained from a qualified legal practitioner in the appropriate jurisdiction rather than from the Internet where the well-meaning and logical opinions you receive on the matter may leave you more ill-advised than if you hadn't asked at all.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say netcat is offensive. It's the most basic network socket program that is often used as the first network socket programming project in school. To say netcat is offensive is like saying ping is offensive.

Comment: I think the OP meant the tool could be used in an offensive manner like a persistent backdoor.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the method of connection (browser, netcat, curl, etc) is as important  as the actions of the connector.  A webserver is set up to serve content, so if you are simply requesting content I think you're ok... just don't cross the line into mal-intent.

Disclaimer: I'm not an attorney and this is simply my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Laws vary by country and state, check with a local legal authority.

Generally speaking, unauthorized connection to a network can get you in trouble.